# How to create individual dll of asp.net mvc project pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC and I need to create separate dll of all pages in project.

Let me explain what should I need. Suppose I have create controller like:

- home.cs
- index.cs
- test1.cs
- test2.cs

and view :

- home.cshtml
- index.cshtml
- test1.cshtml
- test2.cshtml

then I need to create dll like `home.dll` and `index.dll` separately of every page because of if i have publish my project after changes in any one controller that time i just need to update the changeable controller dll only.

I don't know it is possible or not but if anyone know then please suggest me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a very strange requirement. You could place each controller in its own project and reference them all from in your mvc project.

Comment: thanks for fast reply but it is possible to create dll without create own project